# GET a slide, edit it, and POST it again with minor changes

Tags: go, google-slides-api

I was hoping someone could help me with something i've been stuck on. I'm not even sure if it's possible to do.

So i basically have a huge Json file which includes all objects used for a certain slide Specifically i used this GET command:

```
GET https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}
```

I then got a huge 200.000 line Json response which has alot of stuff like colors for each thing, position of every element on each slide ect. I save this as a JSON file on my pc. I only need it once as a form of template.

Then my golang code dynamically edits some of its values (after converting it to structs ofc).
Now i want to POST it back up. It has a new name now, new ID, but 99,9% of the values are the same.

Is it possible to do this?

And sorry in advance. I know people here tend to get mad at "stupid questions" or if i forget to add something, but i'm new here, and i hope I can get some help. Been stuck for a long while.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is a [Go client library](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/slides/v1) that allows you to do this if you're not set on using a REST API. If you are set on using a REST API, you should be able to post [this endpoint](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate):

```
POST https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}:batchUpdate
```

*Side note, the Google documentation (imo) is fantastic, a little googling goes a long ways :)*

Comment: Thank you, 

I did look into the exact same documentation, but it doesnt seem to answer my specific question (Unless i misunderstood something).

So basically, what you linked gives me the option to make requests, and the requests are very limited compared to what i want to do. 

I basically want to POST all the thing I get from my GET, with slightly added things. You cannot do a "Request" for everything it seems. 

English is not my first language, i'm sorry if it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @ErcanCiftci no you cannot send back the response you got with a few changes, the Google API requires the request to contain "commands" basically, for example `createShape`. I'm sorry I misunderstood your question, but you must use the Google API the way the API was designed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if everything can be updated with requests, or does requests have its limitations as well? As i see it, it has a lot of options, but not every aspect can be updated. Am i wrong in this assumption?