# Is there a way to convert JSON data received from Google Slides API back into the original presentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, google-slides-api

I am working on a functionality where I ask the user to input the ID of Google Slide. I then call Google Slides API in my Ruby on Rails backend from where I return to the React frontend a response with the JSON data. For now, I have been successful in getting the JSON data to the frontend, but I have no idea how to convert it back into the slides.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288221/get-a-slide-edit-it-and-post-it-again-with-minor-changes